# Select2 AngularJS selected item is lost when change state

Tags: angularjs, select

I have a problem with my AngularJS component Select2, I create a directive:

```
 app.directive('autocomplete', function() {
  return {
    restrict : 'A',
    link : function( scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
      $(function() {        
        element.select2({      
          formatNoMatches : function() { 
            return 'No results';
          }         
        });
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Implementation:

```
<select id="animals" name="animals" class="form-control" ng-model="item.animals" autocomplete  > 
  <option ng-repeat="animal in animals" value="{{animal.code}}" >{{animal.value}}</option>                  
</select>
```

The component at this point works well, but, I have a simple $state.go that load other view and later return to this main view, when back to the view the selected animal doesn't load **but the value of item.animals contain the previous correct value selected**.

¿How I can selected again the item? I really don't understand why the selection is lost when  change the state.

¡Thanks for advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is why the `ng-options` exists. You could use the `ng-options` and the previous selected value will be loaded correctly.

```
<select id="animals" name="animals" class="form-control"
    ng-model="item.animals" autocomplete=""
    ng-options="animal.code as animal.value for animal in animals">
</select>
```

**Example Plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/5XLjJ2gm9ksjQfmTAPPp?p=preview

Comment: I have been banging my head against this ALL DAY LONG. Thank you ever so much, your answer pointed me in the right direction.